# C# Create Dht Network(monotorrent dht lib)

Tags: c#, dht

So I wanted to add dht to my server and clients. And I looked into monotorrents. And it seemed straightforward but I'm wondering how I could make my own like sort of "torrent" to which all my clients can connect and then the servers that are connected are waiting for connections and the clients ping them to connect. So first i want to make 1 server a node in it already, and I thought I'd go with an infohash, but that didnt seem to work, if someone could just point me the direction? Sorry I'm really new in this p2p dht world. I did find a proper way to ensure that communication is really going where its intended to go, which was already hard for me

thanks in advance